# sort/graph traversal order of a list of objects which "depend" on each other

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class like Foo below that has a "depends_on" attribute which is an array of other `Foo` instances. I would like to be able to take a list of Foos and sort them such that a foo which depends on another foo is greater than it. E.g., if foo `b` depends on foo `a`, the array should be in the order of `[a,b]`. I figured it would be better to give each foo an `order` field and sort on that field as opposed to using `__lt__`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name, depends_on=[]):
        self.order = 0
        self.name = name
        self.depends_on = depends_on

a = Foo('a')
b = Foo('b', [a])
c = Foo('c', [b])
d = Foo('d')
e = Foo('e')
f = Foo('f', [e])
g = Foo('g', [f, b])

foos = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
```

I've made a recursive function similar to this and it appears to work, but I think there is a better way.

On the first pass, I compare every object in the array against each other. If an object x depends on an object y, I increment object x's `order` field by one.

On the second pass, I compare only the foos with an `order` greater or equal to 1; i.e, the foos who are dependent on at least one other foo. Again, I increment the `order` field of this subset of foos if they depend on each other.

I continue this pattern until there are no more comparisons to be made.

```
def recursive_order(order=0):
    compared = 0
    for fooa in [foo for foo in foos if foo.order >= order]:
        for foob in [foo for foo in foos if foo.order >= order]:
            compared += 1
            if fooa in foob.depends_on:
                foob.order += 1
    if compared == 0:
        return
    recursive_order(order + 1)

recursive_order()
foos.sort(key=lambda foo: foo.order)
print [(foo.name, foo.order) for foo in foos]

[('a', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 0), ('b', 1), ('f', 1), ('c', 2), ('g', 2)]
```

I want a list of `foo` that takes the "dependency order" into account. E.g., foo a and foo b have no dependencies and are thus equal. Foo b depends on Foo a, so foo a < foo b ([a,b]. Foo c depends on Foo b, so [a,b,c].

**Edit**

Thanks to  Martijn Pieters for the link to the topological sort. Here is my implementation:

```
def topological_sort(foos):
    provided = set()
    while foos:
        remaining_foos = []
        emitted = False

        for foo in foos:
            if set(foo.depends_on).issubset(provided):
                yield foo
                provided.add(foo)
                emitted = True
            else:
                remaining_foos.append(foo)

        if not emitted:
            raise raise ValueError("cyclic dependency detected")

        foos = remaining_foos

print [foo.name for foo in topological_sort(foos)]

['e', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'c']
```

Comment: You are basically trying to find a graph traversal order; that's not a sorting problem, really.

Comment: @Martijn: they do call it a topological sort, though, so it's hard to complain about the name too much.

Comment: @DSM: ah, yes, it's been a while since I needed to think in terms of graphs, I had forgotten the terminology.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the link! I edited my question with it adapted for this particular problem.